# Result from radio style buttons in Bootstrap 3 not always in post data

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am experimenting with button groups in my Django project that uses Bootstrap 3.

On one page, I have a table with a lot of small choices where the user needs to chose 1 of 3 options, and I thought that the radio button group as described on [the Bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) would be great for that.

Unfortunately, I seem to have different results in my post data every time I submit a form with identical choices. Most of the choices are in the data, but there are always a few missing (not always the same) - ie the "name" is not in the post data, whether I check it with Django or with Firefox developer tools.

Here is the full generated page (shortened when appropriate):

```
<form id="absenceForm" method="post"> 
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='qZTxumvrNvzDHJKSVziEYZc4Y6mJ4Pdb' />

<div class="container">
    <table id="attendance_table" class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Student</th>
                <th class="column column_5">5</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Buzzard, Beaky</td>
                <td class="column column_5">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs active">
                            <input type="radio" name="bb42_5" value="a" checked>A
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                            <input type="radio" name="bb42_5" value="e">E
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                            <input type="radio" name="bb42_5" value="p">P
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                ...         
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Changes for All Weeks" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>

</form>
```

The problem does not occur when I replace the Bootstrap radio buttons with standard radio buttons (without the labels).

Comment: The HTML you posted looks valid. Do you check the POST data only on the Django side or did you try looking into your browser's dev tools network tab too to see what is really being sent?

Comment: Just checked with the Firefox plugin Tamper Data - it's missing in there as well

Comment: How do you submit the form? By using plain HTML `<form>` tag etc. or some JS?

Comment: With plain HTML form tags (<form id="absenceForm" method="post"> ...</form>). Around 9 out of 10 buttons clicked are in the post data, but there are always one or two missing. I submitted the same form multiple times, and there was no pattern as to which ones would be left out

Comment: Sound really strange. I think we may need the full code of your form. For example, I found mentions that if you put `<table>` and `<form>` tags in the wrong order it may cause such behaviour.

Comment: Have done that. Very strange indeed. As the next step I will switch to standard HTML radio buttons to see whether it's the Bootstrap JS stuff that screws it up

Comment: Is there any logic to the missing data between retries? Is click order relevant? If you place the radio buttons outside the `<label>s`, all below the same div?

Comment: I couldn't find any logic to the missing data, and I believe I was consistent with the clicking order as well. If I place the buttons outside the label, the bootstrap formatting won't work anymore

Comment: I have now replaced the Bootstrap Radio Buttons with standard radio buttons without the labels. The problem does not occur there, so this must have something to do with the Javascript in Bootstrap